# using jax.vmap to vectorize along with broadcasting

Tags: python, jax

Consider the following toy example:

```
x = np.arange(3)
# np.sum(np.sin(x - x[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)

cfun = lambda x: np.sum(np.sin(x - x[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
cfuns = jax.vmap(cfun)

# for a 2d x:
x = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
cfuns(x)
```

where `x-x[:,None]` is the broadcasting part and give a 3x3 array.
I want cfuns to be vectorized over each row of x.

```bash
The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on the JAX Tracer object Traced<ShapedArray(int64[2,2])>with<BatchTrace(level=1/0)> with
  val = Array([[[ 0,  1],
        [-1,  0]],

       [[ 0,  1],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX transformations like `vmap`, `jit`, `grad`, etc. are not compatible with standard `numpy` operations. Instead you should use `jax.numpy`, which provides a similar API built on JAX-compatible operations:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

x = jnp.arange(3)

cfun = lambda x: jnp.sum(jnp.sin(x - x[:, jnp.newaxis]), axis=1)
cfuns = jax.vmap(cfun)

# for a 2d x:
x = jnp.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

print(cfuns(x))
# [[ 0.84147096 -0.84147096]
#  [ 0.84147096 -0.84147096]
#  [ 0.84147096 -0.84147096]]
```